# How can I clone zfs disk including the boot partition

Tags: 20.04, zfs

I have ubuntu 20.04 with zfs in one disk (boot + root). I would like to have a larger disk. Is there a way to clone the entire disk with the bpool and rpool to a new larger disk and make it bookable.
I think I can do it with the dd command, but it will not expand the rpool to the entire disk, which is larger. I would also like to make bpool larger.